# Reputation based on value of topic

Tags: discussion, reputation

As I've read this [Value of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79728/value-of-reputation) and people ask about suggestions so I bring one.

I think myself that Q/A reputation should be calculation based of value of its topic. Topic could be defined by value of tags (its combinations etc.) that are used in question.

Let me explain:

> > I am using CodeIgniter, PHP tags as examples only.

I am active SO user and I mainly search and contribute to CodeIgniter tag and sometimes PHP (or its combination). Whenever user asks/answers [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter), Q/A itself gains less interest than pure PHP [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this), but yet it may be a good question/answer. I understand that there is low demand for CodeIgniter but Q/A may have same "value" as pure PHP one, despite that CodeIgniter Q/A has less reputation "reward".

Example (in same period of time):

1.user asks question with tag php it has 20k views 10 upvotes and 3 answers and one is accepted.
2.user asks question with tag CodeIgniter it has 10k views 3 upvotes and 1 accepted answer.

Total reputation output of question with tag `php` is much higher than reputation output of `CodeIgniter` one. But contribution value may be the same! (**or isnt it? and why?**)

---

there are lots of factors that can be added to formula to calculate value of tag or its combinations (eg. php + codeigniter, php + mysql, codeigniter + active-record), like:

- total questions per tag
- total accepted questions per tag
- total answers per tag
- total upvotes/downvotes on question/answer per tag
- total comments
- and more...

Comment: In all of your description you only hinted at this so before I vote, I want to make sure I understand your position.  Are you saying that votes low volume tags such as CodeIgniter should earn more rep than votes in high volume tags such as PHP?

Comment: Yes thats the concept in short, but I am asking this question: "But contribution value may be the same! (or isnt it? and why?)". For example answer that can be answered with 10 users (correctly) should have less reputation output as answer that can be answered only by 1 person. (or 10k users and 100 users just make some relation)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say with the 2nd sentence of that comment.  What does `For example answer that can be answered with 10 users (correctly) should have compute less reputation output as answer that can be answered only by 1 person. (or 10k users and 100 users just make some relation)` mean?  How are you defining whether a question can be answered by 10 users correctly?

Comment: How are you defining whether a question can be answered by 10 users correctly? -> by how question is tagged (and how is tag "popular", what is answer rate/acceptation for that tag - combination of tags etc. and more criteria)

Comment: Lets say PHP question can be answered by 10k users right away simply because there is tons of people that understands PHP. Value of answer stays the same but reputation reward should be lower simply because too many people can give "correct" answer. Why "10k"? because there are lots of answers containing PHP tag so there must be lots of people that can answer.

Comment: I don't disagree with the spirit of this suggestion - fighting the easy rep you can make in some high-traffic tags with "use jQuery" type answers - but a formula to calculate different reputation values doesn't sound like a good idea to me. What if I have a really, really valuable C# answer that rightfully gains lots of upvotes, and never partake in rep-whoring? Why should I be penalized?

Comment: @Pëkka exactly my point! "easy rep". The calculation itself shouldnt be based only on what I wrote, if there is certain amount of upvotes (globaly) the calculation should be capped. But still if low traffic tag is answered-accepted (with 1 upvote) it should generate same amount of rep when high-traffic question is answered-accepted with 2/3 upvotes.

Comment: @Kyslik ahh, so you mean a per-question reputation limit? I see. Jon Skeet suggested that once: [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136059) Sadly, I don't think I've seen a good way to battle easy rep gains from trivial questions - not without severely changing how Stack Overflow's system works.

Comment: What I am saying in previous comment (about capping): Whenever cap of upvotes/downwotes is reached calculation is same for every tag.

Answer (score 8):

I do think are some topics where it is incredibly difficult to earn rep because there are fewer users and fewer votes, so I can see where this could help level the playing field for participants in those tags.

However, why do we need to level the playing field?  Reputation is not a game to be won, despite how some users treat it.  If you really want to compare yourself to your peers, then the tag ["top users"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/codeigniter/topusers) page should give you want your looking for.

That being said, since reputation is roughly the measure of how much the community values your participation, not I'm saying this idea is a bad one.  It certainly would allow users apparent contributions to the site to be weighted more equally, but the cons greatly outweigh the pros.

This would create 4 problems that I see right now:

1. How would you handle adjusting reputation if the value of a topic changes?  Any reputation scaling would be a dynamic thing over time as specific topics become more or less popular, so if the value of a tag would have to change.

   - Would you fix the scaling factor at the time the question is asked?  This would unfairly benefit askers and answers of old questions in tags that used to have high value but now have been scaled down.
   - Likewise, adjusting the rep continually would mean that users rep would change constantly and users would earn and lose privileges without taking any action on their own.
   - As you mentioned in your comments, the value of the vote would be based on the value at the time it was cast, but it means that votes on the same question or answer would no longer count the same.  This contributes to the confusion on how rep is scored that I mention in #3.
2. Tags can change on a question.  How would this impact how the rep was valued on a specific post?  What if a question was mistag specifically to get the higher value rep.  If you don't recompute the rep when the tags of the question change, then users **will** use this to game the system more
3. It creates unnecessarily complication in how reputation is calculated.  Right now the system is pretty straight forward, +10 rep for an answer upvote, +5 for a question upvote, -2 for a downvote.  This system would leave almost everyone completely helpless in trying to understand how the rep was calculated because it depends on the value of the tags (which could change in time).  Simple is always better than overly complicated.
4. As [Flexo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217082/reputation-based-on-value-of-topic/217095#comment703376_217095) astutely points out, poor quality posts in high value tags could net users more rep, especially those that end up getting sympathy upvotes.

Plus, I do think that this system may back fire.  Knowing that their votes are more valuable, users may not vote as much, and you end up with a similar situation whereas contributors in a specific tag still do not get as much rep as their counter parts in lower value tags.

Comment: There is a fourth problem too: any scheme like this would by definition also disproportionately reward poor and ot answers in tags that shouldn't even exist.

Comment: I understand the concept of reputation, I am not reputation "hunter". I stopped that behaviour at my 500 or so. 1. It wouldn't, whatever you gain or loose today stays the same "forever" because at the time you A/Q the value was XXX. 2) after period of time no rep change would apply. 3) it would stay same but [times]* modifier, modifier could be defined as "value of tag" or something simillar to it.  So for example PHP question would earn regular +10, but CodeIgniters +11. I know it is complicated + I am sorry for my pure english skills.