# Why easy googled questions are more popular?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'd like to hear your opinion on this topic. Why are questions that need a deeper understanding of architecture, patterns, algorithms, and "best practices" are less popular than ones that can be easily answered after googling a question's title?

Adding a comment, that inspired me to ask this question:

> I have to find some solutions by
>   myself, that's why I like to ask "best
>   practice" questions. Most of
>   developers are using existing
>   solutions, existing architects,
>   existing algorithms. What if you want
>   to have you own ones? Why when you ask
>   for a log file format, you get an
>   answer "use Log4Net(j)", even if there
>   isn't one? Sorry:)

Comment: This is known as the "bike shed" problem and has been discussed before.  See [The bike shed problem and SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so).

Comment: It doesn't seem a duplicate question, but they are related, indeed. Thank you:)

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41380/why-are-the-least-technical-questions-rewarded-the-most

Comment: and: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/why-is-subjective-the-top-upvoted-tag-for-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, most questions on architecture, patterns, algorithms, "best practices" etc. are vague and badly expressed. Questions on design patterns, for example, often only serve to show that the questioner doesn't understand what a design pattern is. As these kinds of question are so vague, I often vote to close as "not a real question" rather than attempt to answer them.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but can I show an example? 
I wanted to create my own simple logger, that would log a file in a simple format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810348/a-simple-log-file-format
No one gave an answer I needed, so I found a tool by myself. Maybe my question was badly expressed, but if so, than point me my mistakes and I'll try to work on them, help me, rather than throwing it away and answering "Right my query with a join" or "Right my homework with a simple loop algorithm" questions.

Comment: So then we should edit the question to make it less vague and better expressed (and then probably close as duplicate).

Comment: One problem is that I'm not willing to send tendrils of thought through the Internet and rip requirements out of the quivering brain of the person who wants something (although you can probably tell I've fantasized about it).  If there isn't enough information in the question, there isn't, and I'd rather lay out my assumptions in my answer.

Comment: Everyone wants to be [Cthulhu](http://www.cthulhu.org).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because more popular questions can be easily googled? (Correlation does not imply causation)